# Using bind variable with SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a performance gain when using bind variables when working with SQLite on Android?
Can SQLite reuse parsed queries (like Oracle does) and thus save the SQL parsing time?

Thanks.

Alex

Comment: I do not think that it can save the parsed query because AFAIK it does the parsing each time when ever you make any query, as it does the SELECT operation and access each column.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, binding variables in SQLite will give you a performance boost, as you can prepare/compile the statement a single time, then re-use it with bound variables in each iteration of your select/insert/update.